# filters defined in elasticsearch.yml not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I tried defining a custom filter in elasticsearch.yml as below and restarted the node:

```
index:
  analysis:
    filter: 
      myTokenFilter2:
        type: length
        min: 2
        max: 5
```

and tried to use it.

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/_analyze?tokenizer=standard&filters=myTokenFilter2 -d "a aa aaaa aaaaaa",
```

only to find this in the response json

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "remote_transport_exception",
        "reason": "[Domina][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:admin/analyze[s]]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "failed to find global token filter under [myTokenFilter2]"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

what's wrong with my config? Thank you

Comment: What version of ES are you using?

Comment: Version: 2.3.3, Build: 218bdf1/2016-05-17T15:40:04Z, JVM: 1.8.0_20